# Not able to update

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

I am new to Ubuntu and am having troubles Updating. Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9BF3BB4E5E17B5
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ailurus/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found
W:Failed to fetch ...
```

Can someone please help me *figure out what my problem is* and how I might correct it?

Please note: This involves two different PPA's within the error results stated.

Comment: By the comment above YOU are running maverick and want to install a oneiric PPA.    Oneiric Source DOES NOT EXIST in that PPA any way. Do you also have "E:" errors with comments too. It would be most helpful if you would post the entire failed errors comment as the result of this "sudo apt-get update"

Answer (score 2):

This means you are missing a public key which `apt-get` uses to verify the authenticity of a package list. Basically, that the packages you're about to download really were published by the people you think they were (by the look of it, this is a Chromium key, you have a Chromium PPA active right?)

This command will add the key you've referenced (enter it into `Terminal`):

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 5A9BF3BB4E5E17B5
```

And then the NO_PUBKEY problem should go away. As to the rest of it, you'll probably have to paste it all instead of cutting it short :)